# On image click set input value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im trying to set an image from an input box and if i click another image the box change his value and then the first image change his src but i dont know why is not working.This is my script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#skin").change(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        $("#container").attr("src", inputVal);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container2").click(function() {
        var source = document.getElementById("container2").src;
        $("#skin").val(source)
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="skin">
<img id="container" width="200px" height="200px" border-radius="50%">
<img id="container2" src="http://i.imgur.com/xt0IkTL.png">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: In what way is this "*not working*"? You don't need to know *why*, but you do have to tell us what it's not doing that it should, or what it's doing that it shouldn't. Incidentally `</input>` is unnecessary (and invalid HTML), an `<input />` is a void element that can't contain any other content.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? A jsfiddle would help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using jQuery.

So you don't have to use native javascript dom selector.

Second; you have already defined your document ready function. You don't need to call that again.

Wrap your code between the first document ready function.

I strongly recommend you to change your on change method to something else like pressing a button or trigger with something else.

After all these recommendation;

Here how you can do this:

```
<input id="source-changer" type="text" placeholder="Image url huh?" />
<img id="container" width="200px" height="200px" border-radius="50%"><img id="container2" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PjDtgj7qR94/maxresdefault.jpg" width="100">

<!-- sample address here: https://pp.vk.me/c622424/v622424967/39c6c/6poIwEXow7U.jpg -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstImage = $('#container');
    var secondImage = $('#container2');

    $('input#source-changer').blur(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value !== "") {
            firstImage.attr('src', value);
        }
    });

    secondImage.click(function(){
        firstImage.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Test here:

https://jsfiddle.net/upLdgb8y/1/

Comment: the input has a value on the local storage so if you refresh all change will be lost. i change the image from the input value and i have an img storage. whenever you click on an img on the storage the input change and then the img do it too. i didnt mean to change the image on click on the second img but the input

Comment: Ok just change blur to change bro?